# Sorting Lists Using Divide-and-Conquer

Tags: java

I have a homework problem I have been having a lot of trouble with.  I will type the exact wording for the problem here:

> Given k sorted lists L1, L2, ... , Lk of n/k numbers each with 1 <= k
>   <= n, design a divide-and-conquer algorithm to sort all n numbers in
>   the k sorted lists. Your algorithm should run in O(nlogk) time
>   (instead of O(nlogn) time).

I'm guessing the algorithm used will be a modified merge sort but I have no idea where to even start.  Thanks for any help you may give me!

Comment: start by thinking about just 2 lists, then see how to apply that to k lists

Comment: *"I'm guessing the algorithm used will be a modified merge sort but I have no idea where to even start."* - If you know how a merge sort works, you have a BIG clue as to where to start.  If you don't know, try the Wikipedia page on merge sort for a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Make list couples and sort them using merge in o(n). Recourse on results log_k times.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly could you not use binary recursion to the sort the list in O(nlogk)?

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are already sorted, I think what you are looking for is the [k-way merge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm?wprov=sfla1).